# The method "XXX" is ambigious for the type

Tags: java

I got this compilation error in my code :

> The method add(UComponent comp, KopiAlignment constraints); is ambiguous for the type   DBlock ...

I want to create UBlock interface to make abstraction for an existing class DBlock

Here's the code :

The interface UBlock :

```
public interface UBlock extends UComponent, BlockListener {
   public void add(UComponent comp, KopiAlignment constraints);
}
```

The class DBlock :

```
public class DBlock extends JPanel implements  UBlock {
    public void add(UComponent comp, KopiAlignment constraints) {
    } 
}
```

I call the add method in another class :

```
private DBlock blockView;

blockView.add(displays[i], new KopiAlignment(chartPos + leftOffset, i + 1, 1, false));
```

When I remove the implementation of UBlock from DBlock The error does not exist anymore and here is the called method :

```
/**
 * Adds the specified component to the end of this container.
 * Also notifies the layout manager to add the component to 
 * this container's layout using the specified constraints object.
 * This is a convenience method for {@link #addImpl}.
 * <p>
 * Note: If a component has been added to a container that
 * has been displayed, <code>validate</code> must be
 * called on that container to display the new component.
 * If multiple components are being added, you can improve
 * efficiency by calling <code>validate</code> only once,
 * after all the components have been added.
 *
 * @param     comp the component to be added
 * @param     constraints an object expressing 
 *                  layout contraints for this component
 * @exception NullPointerException if {@code comp} is {@code null}
 * @see #addImpl
 * @see #validate
 * @see javax.swing.JComponent#revalidate()
 * @see       LayoutManager
 * @since     JDK1.1
 */
public void add(Component comp, Object constraints) {
    addImpl(comp, constraints, -1);
}
```

So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Cast your value.  That error means that the value you are using could potentially match more than one method, and the compiler can't figure out which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you inherit the other `add` method. This means in your `DBlock` class you have both

```
public void add(UComponent comp, KopiAlignment constraints)
```

and

```
public void add(Component comp, Object constraints)
```

at your disposal.

Now `KopiAlignment` is a subtype of `Object` and I'm guessing `UComponent` is a subtype of `Component`. This means when you call `add` with `UComponent` and `KopiAlignment` as parameters, the parameter types fit both methods, although they formally have a different signature.

There is no real way to fix this as far as I know.

Comment: You can fix these by downcasting when the actual types are disjoint.  If they're not, you can always explicitly choose the more general: `(Object) myConstraints`

Comment: @MikeSamuel but you can't enforce `add(UComponent comp, KopiAlignment constraints)` to be called.

Comment: I think you're right in this case.  The Java bytecode allows you to make such a distinction, but the Java language does not, except via reflection.